# React Native navigating between two screens back & forth

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have **Home** screen where we search for an ItemCode, after we search ItemCode it will get details from API &  screen will navigate to **Screen 1**(Item Details Screen) & from Screen 1 we have a search for ItemNutrients and after search it will get Nutrients & Navigate to **Screen 2** (Nutrients Screen)

In other words

Home -> Screen 1 (Item Details Screen) -> Screen 2 (Nutrients Screen)

After getting the necessary details from API from search for Item Details & Nutrients, User can navigate between Item Details & Nutrients back and forth..

I could navigate from **Screen 1** (item Details) to **Screen2** (Nutrients Screen) and swipe back to **Screen 1** (item Details) but how could I swipe forward to look at **Screen 2** (Nutrients Screen) again without searching for nutrients in **Screen 1** as I already have the data from API for Nutrients.

Any ideas on how to implement this ? this is basically navigate to **Screen 1** to **Screen 2** on search from Screen 1 or if **Screen 2** search is already done and we have data so swipe forward should navigate to **Screen 2**, I can have a button to navigate to **Screen 2**, the button on Screen 1 conditinally appears only when we have API data  for Nutrients Screen and it will navigate to **Screen 2** on that button click, but i need swipe functionality as well to navigate forward

I have Home, Screen 1, Screen 2 in stackNavigator, is it alright or i could use any other navigators to achieve this.

I have researched how to do this and can't find it in the docs anywhere. Please let me know if I am missing it somewhere. Thanks!

Nutrition Context:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const NutriSyncContext = createContext();

const DEFAULT_IS_NUTRI_SCANNED = false;

export const NutriSyncContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isNutritionScanned, setisNutritionScanned] = useState(
    DEFAULT_IS_NUTRI_SCANNED
  );

  // When we first mount the app we want to get the "latest" conversion data
  useEffect(() => {
    setisNutritionScanned(DEFAULT_IS_NUTRI_SCANNED);
  }, []);

  const nutrionScanClick = ({ navigation }) => {
    setisNutritionScanned(true);
    //navigation.navigate("NutritionFacts");
  };

  const contextValue = {
    isNutritionScanned,
    setisNutritionScanned,
    nutrionScanClick,
  };

  return (
    <NutriSyncContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </NutriSyncContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

inside navigation.js

```
const tabPNMS = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function tabPNMSStackScreen() {
  const { isNutritionScanned } = useContext(NutriSyncContext);
  console.log(isNutritionScanned);

  return (
    <tabPNMS.Navigator initialRouteName="PNMSNutrition" tabBar={() => null}>
      <tabPNMS.Screen name="PNMSNutrition" component={PNMSNutrition} />
      {isNutritionScanned ? (
        <tabPNMS.Screen name="NutritionFacts" component={NutritionFacts} />
      ) : null}
    </tabPNMS.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and In stack Navigation:

```
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator();
const SearchStackScreen = () => (
  <NutriSyncContextProvider>
    <SearchStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Search"
      screenOptions={{
        gestureEnabled: false,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#101010",
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
        headerTintColor: "#ffd700",
        headerBackTitleVisible: false, //this will hide header back title
      }}
      headerMode="float"
    >
      <SearchStack.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={Search}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          title: "Search",
          headerTitleAlign: "center",
          headerLeft: () => (
            <Entypo
              name="menu"
              size={24}
              color="green"
              onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
      <SearchStack.Screen
        name="NutriTabs"
        options={() => ({
          title: "PNMS",
          headerTitleAlign: "center",
        })}
        component={tabPNMSStackScreen}
      />
    </SearchStack.Navigator>
  </NutriSyncContextProvider>
);
```

I have NutriSyncContextProvider around the stack, but when I click the button on my page it will call nutrionScanClick method in context class it works just fine but when i do navigation.navigate to the NutritionFacts tab that is enabled i get error saying NutritionFacts tab doesn't exist

I got it working below is the code:

```
 const nutrionScanClick = () => {
    if (!isNutritionScanned) setisNutritionScanned(true);
    else {
      //Make a API call here for new data for the new scanned one's and then navigate
      navigation.navigate("NutritionFacts");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isNutritionScanned) {
      navigation.navigate("NutritionFacts");
    }
  }, [isNutritionScanned]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no swipe back n forth between screens in a stack navigator. You need to use a tab navigator to be able to keep multiple screens like that.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator

```js
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={() => null}>
      <Tab.Screen name="ItemDetails" component={ItemDetails} />
      {showNutrients ? <Tab.Screen name="Nutrients" component={Nutrients} /> : null}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, but Nutrients Screen is conditional, it only appears after Nutrients are searched from Item Details screen, how to hide that tab and show only Item Details screen and after Nutrients are searched or we have data already from API for previous search then show Nutrients Screen  for back & forth navigation

Comment: You can add the screen based on some conditional and then navigate to that. See updated code.

Comment: I have a button click function that is making showNutrients to true and after click it is making the Nutrients tab enable and i could navigate to it,, but the problem is during the button click i am making showNutrients to true and navigating to Nutrients tab by navigation.navigate, if i do that i get the error that page doesn't exists,, I think within the same button click if i make shownutrients = true and navigate it is navigating to the page I think tab is not getting enable by that time even though showNutrients is true I get page doesn't exist, how do i fix it any help plz

Comment: You can either do it in useEffect hook, or just at a setTimeout

Comment: I am already using useEffect hook to set the flag to true, and I am sharing the data using UseContext, as my tab navigation is nested into stack navigator i am sorrounding my stacknavigation with context provider, 

 useEffect(() => {
    setShowNutrients(false);
  }, []);

Comment: The flag will be set next render, after which the useEffect will run. You can navigate immediately after setting it.

Comment: I shared my code above with UseEffect, do you see any issue plz suggest

Comment: UseEffect if i use inside button click i get error, Invalid hook call, hooks cannot be inside function..

Comment: You need to navigate in another useEffect, where you add `isNutritionScanned` as a dependency and check if it's true inside the hook before navigating, not immediately after setting the state. Setting state in React is async, it doesn't update immediately.